# How to get coordinates from a image using android CROP function?

Tags: android, image, coordinates, android-canvas, android-crop

In my application the user can upload an image, then he can select a part of it using the android **CROP Function** *(see example image 1)*.

I want to get the coordinates of the selected area (see example image 2) by the user using the **CROP Function** or other similar method.

[Example Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cll8R.jpg)

[Example Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o5bQx.png)

Comment: Android does not have a "CROP Function". There are many [image cropping libraries available for Android](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/45).

Comment: And what about **"Intent crop = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP")"** ?

Comment: Android does not have a `CROP` `Intent`: https://commonsware.com/blog/2013/01/23/no-android-does-not-have-crop-intent.html

Comment: Thanks a lot @CommonsWare

Answer (score 1):

This Github project is exact solution for your query

Project link: https://github.com/yulu/crop-image-layout

**Output**

[image]